# Is it necessary to specify a data source for a report definition file after specifying a data set for it?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

When creating a SSRS project in Visual Studio, I

- first created a data source for a database connection,
- then a data set for a SQL script, and
- then a report definition .rdl file.

When creating the data set file, I specified a data source in its properties.

[image]

When creating the report definition .rdl file, I specified a data source and a data set in its properties in "Report Data" panel.

[image]

[image]

For a report definition:

- Is it necessary to specify a data source  file after specifying a data set for it, if the data source has been already specified for the data set?
- What happens if I specify a data source different from the one for the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are getting at but in simple terms...

From the designer, you can add a dataset to a report either by selecting an existing shared dataset or by creating anew one.

If you use a shared dataset, the dataset has it's own datasource properties that usually reference a shared data source. Therefore when adding a shared dataset to a report, there is no need to add a datasource to the report, the report will connect to the database as follows.

```
Report --> DataSet --> Shared Dataset --> Shared DataSource --> Database
```

When you add a dataset directly (not a shared dataset) then you need to point the dataset to a datasource reference in the report itself. This report datasource can be embedded or it can reference a shared datasource. So the report would connect to the database via either of these routes

```
Report --> Embedded DataSet --> DataSource --> Shared DataSource --> Database

Report --> Embedded DataSet --> DataSource --> Embedded DataSource --> Database
```